# iterate through azure storage absolute path c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

```
 CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);
            var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
```

I want to check which is latest file uploaded into `sourcename`
I tried using below code -

```
sourceName.Uri = {https://test.file.core.windows.net/XC/MainFolder/}
sourceName.Uri.AbsolutePath = {/XC/MainFolder/}

 var directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourceName.Uri.AbsolutePath);
            var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                          orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                          select f).First();
```

error as - 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\XC\MainFolder'.'

which is obvious as it is not a local folder.

how can i use https://test.file.core.windows.net/XC/MainFolder/ to loop and check the latest file ? instead go into each and every file and sub-folder and check its lastModified property , is there any wasy way to do?

Comment: Will the files be in any subdirectory structure? Or would the files just be in the file share without any subdirectories?